# Neo4J cypher query to get nodes connected by paths with the same generic attribute

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I'm trying to create a cypher query that returns me the nodes connected by a given range of hops (i.e. 1..5), where all the relationships between these hops share a same attribute value, without specifying this attribute.

So I would like to do something like

```
MATCH (a {type: 'cin1'})-[rels:Next*1.. {value: 1}]->(b {type: 'cancer'}) 
RETURN (a), (b)
```

But without specifying that the value on the edges should be one, they just need to be equal among all the edges in the hopping process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would add an upper bound to your path. Or use (all)shortestPath(s)

Also make sure to look up `a` and `b` by indexed label + property combination.

And then you can use a predicate on the relationships-collection that forms your path.

```
MATCH (a:Label {type: 'cin1'})
MATCH (b:Label {type: 'cancer'})
MATCH shortestPath((a)-[rels:Next*1..20]->(b))
WHERE ALL(r in tail(rels) WHERE (head(rels)).value = r.value)
RETURN (a), (b)
```

Comment: I wonder if the performance of this is reasonable.  It seems to me that in the other way you only hop when the value matches the specified one, whereas in this way you make all possible hops and the filter them, right?