# Finding Specific Path in Neo4j Quickly

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I've [recently asked about how to find all paths between two types os nodes in a way where all the edges in the path had the same attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38095528/neo4j-cypher-query-to-get-nodes-connected-by-paths-with-the-same-generic-attribu) (like the same ID). This would be something like:

```
MATCH (a {type: 'cin1'})-[rels:Next*1.. {value: 1}]->(b {type: 'cancer'}) 
RETURN (a), (b)
```

where instead of having *value: 1* I would have *value: same for all edges*.

I found a way to solve this by using something like this (as answered in my other question):

```
MATCH (a:Label {type: 'cin1'})
MATCH (b:Label {type: 'cancer'})
MATCH shortestPath((a)-[rels:Next*1..20]->(b))
WHERE ALL(r in tail(rels) WHERE (head(rels)).value = r.value)
RETURN (a), (b)
```

The problem I'm having is that this approach first create all the possible different paths to then filter them, which in my case creates exponentially many paths. For example, take the following graph

[image: graph example]:

The approach given will first match all the paths:

```
id:1 -> id:1 -> id:1 
id:1 -> id:2 -> id:1 
id:1 -> id:1 -> id:2 
id:1 -> id:2 -> id:2 
id:1 -> id:2 -> id:3 
...
```

And only then filter these options to return *1->1->1*,  *2->2->2*,  *3->3->3* and so on. Therefore it turns out that this approach is very not effective, and I wonder if there is an easier way.

Comment: Is there any way you can optimize your relationships? Right now my assumption is they're all using the same label with differing attributes. Can you change them into labels instead, or is this not feasible?

Comment: is not feasible :/ basically you have too many of them

Comment: I was afraid of that. While I understand your performance concerns, I'm wondering if you've run this on a sample dataset to confirm that performance is truly an issue. I'm guessing you've got a huge dataset with a fairly massive web of connections?

Comment: Yes! Some hundred thousand nodes! It runs perfectly on a smaller dataset though

Comment: I'm wondering about that WHERE ALL clause...is that being used in the shortest path execution (and if so, is that performing the check on every single relationship in the entire path with every single evaluation), or is that only being executed at the end of the exhaustive search to filter? Also, can you give any info on the root nodes (type cin1)? How many are there? How many interested relationships do they have on average? Would it make more sense to iterate queries across them than to use one super query like you're doing now?

Comment: I'm not sure on that, but I think that it is being executed only at the end! There is a bunch of Cin 13 nodes, and they can have hundreds to thousands relationships. I'm basically trying to model a health database with Neo4J and this modelling has some advantages (it is very easy to find out a fully specified sequence of diagnosis).

Answer (score 0):

As far as optimizations, I'd first look at ways to optimize quick matches on start and end nodes, as that should significantly reduce the nodes scanned.

My hunch is that you probably aren't indexing on :Label.type, and if that's your primary means of matching to nodes, this is probably something to consider and test.

It may also be effective to see if you can add labels on your start or end nodes. At the least it seems like :Cancer could likely be applied effectively, though if this is meant to be a more general medical app this kind of query would need to be effective for many diseases, so I'm not sure if this is feasible for you.

In that case I think your best bet is to optimize the shortestPath(), and PROFILE your query to ensure that your WHERE ALL clause is being used during calculation of the shortestPath, and not as a filter after exhaustive searches (see [Shortest Path](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/#query-shortest-path) and [Shortest Path Planning](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/#query-shortestpath-planning)). If profiling reveals that it's being used as a filter rather than while constructing shortest path, you'll want to see if you can pick a more efficient predicate shortest path will fail fast for non-matching patterns.