# Back-reference neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Can I use some back-reference sort of mechanism in neo4j? I'm not interested in what matches the query, just that it is the same thing in many places. Something like:

```
MATCH (a:Event {diagnosis1:11})
MATCH (b:Event {diagnosis1:15})
MATCH (c:Event {diagnosis1:5})
MATCH (a)-[rel:Next {PatientID:*}]->(b)
MATCH (b)-[rel1:Next {PatientID:\{1}]->(c)
```

The idea is that I just require the attribute IDs from both edges to be the same, without specifying it. The whole purpose of it would be not generating all possible matchings, to then filter them, but only hop in the specific places.

I've asked something similar in a more specific way [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38183686/finding-specific-path-in-neo4j-quickly).

Edit: I know WHERE clauses can be used for that, but they filter the query AFTER matching the edges and nodes. I want to do that DURING the matching!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a `WHERE` clause with simple references, there's no need for back references:

```
MATCH (a)-[rel:Next]->(b)
MATCH (b)-[rel1:Next]->(c)
WHERE rel.PatientID = rel1.PatientID
```

---

**Update**

First of all, Cypher is a declarative query language: you express what you want, the runtime takes care of executing and optimizing it any way it can, so it's not that obvious that it would do it the way you think it will, or that using "back references" would magically solve the problem; it's just another way of writing the same thing.

So, your problem is that the match creates all the relationship pairs before filtering them. How about splitting the match in 2 phases using `WITH`?

```
MATCH (a:Event {diagnosis1:11})-[rel:Next]->(b:Event {diagnosis1:15})
WITH a, b, rel
MATCH (b)-[rel1:Next]->(c:Event {diagnosis1:5})
WHERE rel1.PatientID = rel.PatientID
```

That should only select the second relationships that match the first, but I'm not sure if it's an O(n^2) algorithm in Cypher's runtime.

Otherwise, if you drop to the Java API (which would mean either an extension or a procedure, depending on your version of Neo4j), you can probably implement in O(n) by

- scanning all the relationships between `a` and `b`, indexing them by `PatientID` in some multimap (see Guava, or use a `Map<K, Collection<V>>`); this is O(n)
- then doing the same for all the relationships between `b` and `c`, still O(n)
- iterate on the keys of one multimap to get the values in both and match them, still O(n)

Comment: that is not what I want, when you do that you generate ALL the matchings and then filter then! It is inefficient! I don't want to generate all the matchings, just the ones where the IDs are the same

Comment: I've updated the answer, based on your extra context.

Comment: Thank you very much! I wonder if there is some material on how to change the java api. The version with "WITH" doesn't seem to work :/.

Comment: You don't change the Neo4j core API, you use it [in an extension (pre-3.x), a procedure (starting at 3.x)](http://neo4j.com/docs/2.3.3/server-extending.html) or by [using Neo4j embedded](http://neo4j.com/docs/2.3.3/tutorials-java-embedded.html). Regarding the version with `WITH`, I just wrote it on SO without testing it on any data, so I could easily have made a mistake (even if I can't see one even now); it should look something like that anyway.

Comment: Do you think I can use the Gremlim language to get that done? I am currently using the server with a python client, I'm using the py2neo interface to acess the server, can I call the procedure just like any other function? Because all the examples I see are using java, not the query itself.

Comment: I'm also wondering if this can be a procedure, because it involves changing the graph does its transversal.

Comment: Procedures are called [via Cypher](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/#_calling_procedures), you can call them from whatever client you want. However, they are written in a JVM language and deployed as a jar in Neo4j, juste like extensions. I don't know much about Gremlin, but I think it's an alternative to Cypher, whereas to use the Java core API, the code has to be in the same JVM as Neo4j. Don't deploy code to Neo4j unless you're sure you have no other way, though.